# Is it possible to refresh Dynamics CRM subgrid from an HTML webresource?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-dynamics, webresource

On contact form, for a custom entity say `ABC`, I am opening HTML web resource using `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource()`at onClick of a custom button to add records. Once the user create record form HTML web resource, I need to refresh sub-grid.

Below is the code snippet that I am using to refresh the subgrid of entity `ABC` on contact form. 
`parent.Xrm.Page.getControl("subgrid_abc").refresh();`

I am expecting that this code snippet should refresh the subgrid on Contact form once the record is saved. But it is not working as par my requirements. Any idea how can we refresh the subgrid on main form from pop-up of an HTML webresource?

Comment: Do you know why it isnt working? E.g. an error message shown?

Comment: no error, nothing

Comment: Hi Mohsin, have you gotten anywhere with this? I have a similar requirement and cannot figure out how I can access parent page's elements.